# Conditional Footer on SSRS Email Subscriptions

Tags: reporting-services

At my company, we are big on knowing who provided what data so each of our reports have a footer as such

[image]

```
="Report Executed On: " & Globals!ExecutionTime & Environment.NewLine & "Report Executed By: " & MID(User!UserID,InStr(User!UserID,"\")+1, Len(User!UserID)) & Environment.NewLine & "Page " & Globals!PageNumber & " of " & Globals!OverallTotalPages
```

This works fine when a report is run from the Reports Manager Portal but if I set up an email subscription where this footer is included, the emailed version of the report contains my name as the Executor which is technically correct but I don't always want my name on EVERYTHING. Is there some expression trickery I can do to hide this portion of my report footers when a subscription is executed? Other options?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate account to execute the subscription under then hide that part if the user name matches this account.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a hidden parameter that has the `User!UserID` as a default value and use this in your footer.  When you create a subscription you can overwrite the default.